# span tag text not change using JQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i cant give json value to span tag 
actually i am using jquery ajax function

```
 var productId = $("#product_id").text();
    var city = $("#spn-deliveryloccookies").text();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Product/est_time',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { 'city': city, productid: productId },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (res) {
            //your success code
            alert(res);
            //$("#p_price").html("");

            $("#p_price").text(res.ourPrice);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("some error");
        }
    });
});
```

after that it produce result 
[image: firebug result]
and the web page having  a

> 

i cant give the text value in to span tag

in my ajax function  **success block there have **alert(res);** and it work fine it produce result**

[image: image link] 
 but

$("#p_price").text(res.ourPrice); not work

Comment: `res` is a string, use `dataType: "json",`  it will parse it to js object

Comment: thanks genius it now work... simple thing irritated me.

Comment: Aslo note that GET has no contentType. There is no content body being sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the json string to javascript object. Then only you access its properties.

```
  $("#p_price").text(JSON.parse(res).ourPrice);
```

Comment: This is alternate solution to using dataType:JSON. It will work, try the updated code. If any error please comment. @SkAsraf